# KVM - WFH / Gaming dual monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport, kvm-switch

I have a gaming pc using 2 monitors, and now will be working from home using an HP laptop as well. I do not have space to set up a separate desk so I would like to use a KVM switch to use my own dual monitors, keyboard, and mouse with both computers. The KVM switch i purchased takes an hdmi, displayport, and usb from both computers. The output for monitors is one HDMI and one display port, however my monitors both take HDMI. I tried using an hdmi cord with a displayport adapter which did not register to the monitor. And i tried a hdmi to displayport cord to see if that made a difference but I can only get the monitor plugged in via hdmi to work.